# Use sed to only replace namespace in an element that has a parent element with a given attribute value

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to replace the namespace in an xml file using sed (I've given up trying to do it from ant, where it is required).
The main issue is that that there is a repeating list of elements - not all of which need replacing.

Xml file:

```
<xml-fragment>
  <imp:exportedItemInfo instanceId="WikiDS_v1_PS" typeId="ProxyService" xmlns:imp="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/importexport">
    <imp:properties>
      <imp:property name="dataclass" value="com.bea.wli.sb.resources.config.impl.XmlEntryDocumentImpl"/>
      <imp:property name="isencrypted" value="false"/>
    </imp:properties>
  </imp:exportedItemInfo>
  <imp:exportedItemInfo instanceId="NonShared/wikitest/FileUploadManagementDS_v1_BS_WSDL" typeId="WSDL" xmlns:imp="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/importexport">
    <imp:properties>
      <imp:property name="dataclass" value="com.bea.wli.sb.resources.config.impl.WsdlEntryDocumentImpl"/>
      <imp:property name="isencrypted" value="false"/>
    </imp:properties>
  </imp:exportedItemInfo>
  <imp:exportedItemInfo instanceId="NonShared/wikitest/WikiTestDS_v1_BS" typeId="BusinessService" xmlns:imp="http://www.bea.com/wli/config/importexport">
    <imp:properties>
      <imp:property name="dataclass" value="com.bea.wli.sb.resources.config.impl.XmlEntryDocumentImpl"/>
      <imp:property name="isencrypted" value="false"/>
    </imp:properties>
  </imp:exportedItemInfo>
</xml-fragment>
```

So in this case I want to replace the namespace in the block that has a typeId of ProxyService but none of the others.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to do this with sed so I used a third party ant task http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/ which works nicely

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to replace only the lines matching the particular pattern.

```
sed -e '/typeId="ProxyService"/s/xmlns:imp="http:\/\/www.bea.com\/wli\/config\/importexport"/xmlns:imp="http:\/\/www.bea.com\/wli\/config\/importexport2"/' new.xml
```

This will replace your namespace only in the lines matching "typeId="ProxyService" . I've just added a 2 to your namespace, but you can replace that with any string of your choice.

Comment: Oops my edit didn't work - I did add that the namespace I wish to change is the one for the attribute 'dataclass' in the child 'property' element. I thought this may be possible using the g switch somehow - i.e., match from ProxyService until the closing imp:exportedItemInfo tag